# How to reduce output from Exception Data property with NLog JsonLayout?

Tags: entity-framework-core, nlog

Right now using NLog JsonLayout to serialize the exception details like this:

```
<target>
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="Exception" encode="false" layout="${exception:format=@}"/>
```

The exception "Data" property contains some huge byte arrays, that I want to have truncated.

Have tried using `${exception:format=@:truncate=500}`, but the output is then being cut so the format gets destroyed.

How can I limit the output, while Json format remains valid?

```
{
"Date": "2021-11-23T09:56:30.3214775Z",
"Application": "MyApp",
"Logger": "MyLogger",
"Level": "ERROR",
"Exception": {
    "Type": "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException",
    "Entries": [
        {
            "Entity": {
                "Id": 0,
                "SomeStuff": {
                    "Id": 0,
                    "File": [
                        {
                            "Name": "myfile.pdf",
                            "Data": [
                                37,
                                80,
                                68,
                                7
```

Comment: You can consider using `truncate` like this `<attribute name="A" layout="${somelayout:truncate=5000}"/>` (Supported by NLog 4.6.3 and later)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :)

Comment: If using `${exception:format=@}` and have a crazy exception, then you can override the reflection for that exception-type (Ex. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException`) using `RegisterObjectTransformation`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

NLog 4.7 allows you to override the reflection for a specific exception-type (Ex. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException) like this:

```cs
    LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s =>
       s.RegisterObjectTransformation<System.Net.WebException>(ex => new {
          Type = ex.GetType().ToString(),
          Message = ex.Message,
          StackTrace = ex.StackTrace,
          Source = ex.Source,
          InnerException = ex.InnerException,
          Status = ex.Status,
          Response = ex.Response.ToString(),  // Call your custom method to render stream as string
       })
    );
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#customize-object-reflection